# Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MDCSwipeToChooseDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to do a "Tinder Swipe" in Swift using MDCSwipeToChoose Delegate. I am following this tutorial https://github.com/modocache/MDCSwipeToChoose

But after installing the CocoaPod and inserting the code from the tutorial I get the error "Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MDCSwipeToChooseDelegate'". Here is the part of the code in my ViewController that contains the error:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var options = MDCSwipeToChooseViewOptions() // Here is where I get the error
    options.delegate = self //And the same error here
    options.likedText = "Keep"
    options.likedColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    options.nopeText = "Delete"
    options.onPan = { state -> Void in
        if state.thresholdRatio == 1 && state.direction == MDCSwipeDirection.Left {
            println("Photo deleted!")
        }
    }

    var view = MDCSwipeToChooseView(frame: self.view.bounds, options: options)
    view.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "photo.png")
    self.view.addSubview(view)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ViewController should implement the `MDCSwipeToChooseDelegate` protocol. So it should be like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MDCSwipeToChooseDelegate {
```

And you might want to implement the methods of this protocol (there are optional but depending what you want to do, you may have to use them)

```
func viewDidCancelSwipe(view: UIView) -> Void

func view(view: UIView, shouldBeChosenWithDirection: MDCSwipeDirection) -> Bool

func view(view: UIView, wasChosenWithDirection: MDCSwipeDirection) -> Void
```

Comment: Thank you now I have the same error but now not on a code line but directly after super.viewDidLoad(). 

I have implemented the methods but did not show them in the code above.

Comment: Is it the exact same error? "Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MDCSwipeToChooseDelegate'"

Comment: Yes, the same error "Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MDCSwipeToChooseDelegate'"

Comment: The error happens after super.viewDidLoad()? This seems strange. You do not have anything else in the logs?

Comment: Yes it was really strange. Now I tried to run the app even if there was a error and the error disappeared. Don't know why it didn't disappeared when I saved the file but now it works. Thanks  a lot for helping me!

Comment: You're welcome. It was probably a XCode error. It sometimes gets mixed up :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement all the necessary methods?

```
func viewDidCancelSwipe(view: UIView) -> Void

func view(view: UIView, shouldBeChosenWithDirection: MDCSwipeDirection) -> Bool

func view(view: UIView, wasChosenWithDirection: MDCSwipeDirection) -> Void
```

Comment: Yes, so unfortunately thats not the problem.